# How can I make my duck lay in the box

Tags: birds, eggs

I have two ducks and a drake. Ten days ago, I found an egg on the ground, out of the hen house. Today, I found another one, somewhere else.

- Has the duck laid other eggs during this ten days? The run is very large and I cannot find anything there.
- Can I do anything, so that she lays in the box?

Comment: Have you provided a soft nest inside the box or nesting materials so she can build her own nest?

Comment: @Elmy Yes, the There are some nestes in which my hens lay, but it seems that my ducks don't like it. Besides, she can make her own nest, because there is enough straw.

Answer (score 1):

You could try purchasing some fake ceramic eggs and put them in the nest box, which may encourage her to lay there. I've never had ducks mixed with chickens, but this is what I did for my chickens.

Comment: +1, there are some fake eggs there, but she still doesn't lay there.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience domestic ducks are not good mothers.  I suspect this is because there tends to be a lot of egg incubator use in domestic duck breeding. Darwin does not weed out the poor mothers so, they get more prominent.

Ducks also tend to lay fewer eggs than chickens.

When the duck hen is laying eggs, keep them (as you have 3 I would keep them all together all the time) in a smaller area that you can check easily. Gather the duck eggs and put them under chicken to hatch.  You will want to put them all under the chicken hen at the same time without any other eggs.  You may need to use additional 'fake' eggs to satisfy the chickens egg sitting needs.

There is a bunch of complexities in the above that I have not fully addressed. Maybe we need more related questions?